Add json-validator result to validated json object
I´m trying to validate an incoming json string against a json schema, but instead of throwing an exception if that validation fails, I´d like to forward the validation errors together with the validated json payload:
from("direct:myValidator")
.log("Validating json...")
.to("json-validator:myschema.json") 
.onException(org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidationException.class)
.continued(true)
.transform().???;

So ideally I would have a a json object like
"validatedJson":*original json*, "validationResult":*excepted integer but got string*"
after that. I understand that with simple and ${exception.message} I can access the errors. But I didn´t manage to turn that into valid json and combine it with the original message.

You need to process the message with a Processor to transform it accordingly. You can do something like this in your onException block:
.process(exchange -> {
  String originalJson = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
  JsonValidationException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, JsonValidationException.class);
  String out = "{\"validatedJson\": \"" + originalJson + "\", \"validationResult\": \"" + cause.toString() + "\"}";
  exchange.getIn().setBody(out);
})

First you will read the body as the original json. You can also get the exception as you already know. And then you will create a new body, containing the original json and the error message. We're creating the json by hand, but of course, with more complex structure, you should use a library.

Thanks! This even reduces it to the relevant part of the exception:String out = "{\"validationErrors\":\"" + cause.getErrors().toString() + "\", \"validatedJson\":" + originalJson + "}";
